# Android: How to cancel fragment switch from onPause method

Tags: android, android-fragments, onpause

My case is quite simple: I have `fragment A` and switch it to `fragment B` with `NavigationDrawer`. In `onPause` method of `fragment A` I save the data in DB. But if some fields are empty, I must show alert and must not replace `fragment A` to `fragment B`, of course.

Is there any way to cancel fragment replace from `fragment A` `onPause` method?

Thank you!

Comment: no, there is no way. You have to check fields before confirming to replace A to B. You'd better move your code where you write to db into the place before you switch fregments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need hook method to Fragment A from your Activity that has NavigationDrawer. If you catch navigation click event from Fragment A and return true or false to stop navigation drawer click event. If you can send some code i can help to implementation or at least a git repo.